# Linux - how can I find phrases from array

Tags: linux, terminal, console

For exmaple, I have four phrases:

john
doe
hello
world

I want to find any files that contain any of these phrases. All 4, 3, 2 or only the one of them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep -E "pattern1|pattern2" /dev/null {}\;
```